# Filter Scala DataFrame: Error integer number too large

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter

I have a very large DataFrame of about 4 billion records. When I filter to a specific row number value I need (shown below), I get an error when filtering as an integer. So I tried converting my row number column to a long and filtering as a long, but that does not work. How can I get around this?

```
df = dfOriginal
.withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(Window.orderBy($"col_name".desc)))
.withColumn("row_num_long", col("row_num").cast("long"))
```

Filtering like this throws an error: `error: integer number too large`

```
df.filter($"row_num" > 2232572249)
```

Filtering on the long version of the row numbers does not actually return anything. The count returns as 0.

```
df.filter($"row_num_long" > 2232572249L).count()
```

Comment: `row_number` is long as it is. You should not need to cast. The first variant should work, if you just add `L` to the constant. The second one should work too OTH, I don't know why it doesn't for you. Maybe your dataframe isn't as big as you think it is? Try `count` without filtering.

Comment: @Dima I think you're wrong with this, if you create a simple df and use row_number then printSchema, then it shows up as integer! although `Maybe your dataframe isn't as big as you think it is?` is possible, what I meant is about the first part of your comment.

Comment: @AminMal yeah, I don't know. I googled the doc, and it said "bigint" somewhere ... but maybe it was wrong. There is also a `monotonically_increasing_id` function apparently, which is also supposed to return bigint. But it's not guaranteed to be consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is because `row_number` functions works with integers.

> The **row_number()** is a window function in Spark SQL that assigns a row number (sequential integer number) to each row in the result DataFrame.

And still, when you try to cast it to Long, it first needs to be computed, and then the casting process begins. So when being computed, it cannot pass the maximum integer value which is `2147483647`, it overflows. So when you try to do:

```scala
df.filter($"row_num_long" > 2232572249L).count()
```

There is literally no rows, since there is no integer greater than `2232572249L`. I think you can report this issue to spark.